# Slow ASP Classic authentication with LDAP

Tags: asp-classic, ldap, ado

I use asp classic to authenticate a user with LDAP. There are about 10 000 accounts in the LDAP and the check for authentication in asp is quite slow (15 seconds).

I used on the same server the LDP tool ([from Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772839%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)) and everything (from connection, binding and search) is fast.

Here's my code, I tried 3 different options and I had same results :

Using SQL instructions :

```
Dim oConn: Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.Provider = "ADsDSOOBJECT"
oConn.Properties("User ID") = Username
oConn.Properties("Password") = Password
oConn.Properties("Encrypt Password") = True
oConn.Open "DS Query", Username, Password
Dim Query: Query = "SELECT sAMAccountName FROM 'LDAP://ldap.mydomain.com/CN=" & Username & ",CN=Users' WHERE objectCategory = 'person' AND objectClass='user' AND SAMAccountName = '" & Username & "' "
Dim oCmd: Set oCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set oCmd.ActiveConnection = oConn
oCmd.CommandText = Query
Dim oRs: Set oRS = oCmd.Execute
If oRS.BOF Or oRS.EOF Then
    ' Authentication failed
Else
    ' Autentication passed
End If
...
```

Using LDAP instructions :

```
Dim oConn: Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.Provider = "ADsDSOOBJECT"
oConn.Properties("User ID") = Username
oConn.Properties("Password") = Password
oConn.Properties("Encrypt Password") = True
oConn.Open "DS Query", Username, Password
Dim Query: Query = "<LDAP://ldap.mydomain.com>;(samAccountName=" & Username & ");samAccountName;subtree"
Dim oCmd: Set oCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set oCmd.ActiveConnection = oConn
oCmd.CommandText = Query
Dim oRs: Set oRS = oCmd.Execute
If oRS.BOF Or oRS.EOF Then
    ' Authentication failed
Else
    ' Autentication passed
End If
...
```

Using IADS objects :

```
Dim DSODomaine
Dim DSOContainer

On Error Resume Next

Set DSODomaine = GetObject("LDAP:")
Set DSOContainer = DSODomaine.OpenDSObject("LDAP://ldap.mydomain.com", Username, Password, ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION + ADS_SERVER_BIND)

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    ' Authentication failed
Else
    ' Autentication passed
End If
...
```

The 3 examples are all slow. What could I do to improve performance using asp classic ?

Answer (score 0):

Ancient thread, but you can include the port in the address like
`LDAP://ldap.mydomain.com:389` - that should speed up your query

**Later edit** - if your issue is exactly 15 seconds delay, this will help:

Windows tries to retrieve a fresh CRL (certificate revocation list) from both its own and third-party servers. This looks like it times out in exactly 15 seconds. This might be the case if the machine is isolated or doesn’t have internet access to those resources (blocked/firewall, slow connection etc).

If your CA/Certificate is already available on the webserver you try to lower the timeout to see if it solves the issue?

We just need to follow these steps on Vault Server:

1. Start gpedit.msc -> Local Computer policy -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Internet Communication Management -> Internet Communication Settings -> Turn off automatic root certificate update = Enabled
2. Start gpedit.msc -> Local Computer policy -> Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Public Key Policy -> Certificate Path Validation Path. Select tab “Network Retrieval” and enable the “Define these policy settings”. Deselect “Automatic update root….” And most important set the timeout values to 1.